# Bootstrap Mega Menu wrong positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

At the moment I'm building a website using Bootstrap 3 and Mega Menu. Everything is fine except one unpleasant moment - my Mega Menu has a wrong positioning. Instead of opening inside the `.container`, it ignores the container and opens outside it. You can open the snippet in a full screen and see that it opens outside the container. I broke my head, but I still can not understand where the problem is.

```css
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}


.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
  border-right: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 17px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 285px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 19px solid transparent;
  border-left: 19px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  left: 283px;
  z-index: 8;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #999;
  white-space: normal;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover,
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu form {
  margin: 3px 20px;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 <div class="container">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top sticky-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navMain">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right custom-pull">
        <li><a href="about.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="attorneys.html">Attorneys</a></li>
        <li><a href="practice-areas.html">Practice Areas</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Collection <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">New in Stores</li>
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/3498db/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 1"></a>
                      <h4><small>Summer dress floral prints</small></h4>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button>
                      <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Item -->
                    <div class="item">
                      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/ef5e55/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 2"></a>
                      <h4><small>Gold sandals with shiny touch</small></h4>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">9,99 €</button>
                      <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Item -->
                    <div class="item">
                      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/2ecc71/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 3"></a>
                      <h4><small>Denin jacket stamped</small></h4>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button>
                      <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Item -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- End Carousel Inner -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.carousel -->
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">View all Collection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Dresses</li>
                <li><a href="#">Unique Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Image Responsive</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Auto Carousel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Newsletter Form</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Four columns</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Tops</li>
                <li><a href="#">Good Typography</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Jackets</li>
                <li><a href="#">Easy to customize</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Glyphicons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pull Right Elements</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Pants</li>
                <li><a href="#">Coloured Headers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Primary Buttons & Default</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Calls to action</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Accessories</li>
                <li><a href="#">Default Navbar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lovely Fonts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Responsive Dropdown </a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Newsletter</li>
                <form class="form" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                </form>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
            
        
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add position relative to your navbar (or container, depends on the width of the mega menu you want to achieve)

```
.navbar-collapse {
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}


.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
  border-right: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 17px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 285px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 19px solid transparent;
  border-left: 19px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  left: 283px;
  z-index: 8;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #999;
  white-space: normal;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover,
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu form {
  margin: 3px 20px;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}


.navbar-collapse {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 <div class="container">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top sticky-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navMain">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right custom-pull">
        <li><a href="about.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="attorneys.html">Attorneys</a></li>
        <li><a href="practice-areas.html">Practice Areas</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Collection <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">New in Stores</li>
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/3498db/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 1"></a>
                      <h4><small>Summer dress floral prints</small></h4>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button>
                      <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Item -->
                    <div class="item">
                      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/ef5e55/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 2"></a>
                      <h4><small>Gold sandals with shiny touch</small></h4>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">9,99 €</button>
                      <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Item -->
                    <div class="item">
                      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/2ecc71/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 3"></a>
                      <h4><small>Denin jacket stamped</small></h4>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button>
                      <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Item -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- End Carousel Inner -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.carousel -->
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">View all Collection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Dresses</li>
                <li><a href="#">Unique Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Image Responsive</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Auto Carousel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Newsletter Form</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Four columns</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Tops</li>
                <li><a href="#">Good Typography</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Jackets</li>
                <li><a href="#">Easy to customize</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Glyphicons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pull Right Elements</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Pants</li>
                <li><a href="#">Coloured Headers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Primary Buttons & Default</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Calls to action</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Accessories</li>
                <li><a href="#">Default Navbar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lovely Fonts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Responsive Dropdown </a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Newsletter</li>
                <form class="form" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                </form>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
            
        
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
 </div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much